# Sort Plots by year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this data frame where I want to graph 3 plots based on year with x and y being Unspcs Desc and Total_Price. For example plot one will be specific to the year 2018 and only contain contents of Unspsc Desc and Total_Price for 2018

```
Material  Total_Price   Year_Purchase
Gasket     50,000        2018
Washer     6,000         2019
Bolts      7,000         2019
Nut        3,000         2020 
Gasket     25,000        2019
Gasket     2500          2020
Washer     33500         2018
Nuts       7000          2019
```

The code I was using

```
dw.groupby(['Unspsc Desc', 'Total_Price']).Year_Purchase.sort_values().plot.bar()
```

Comment: sounds like you want to groupby year then

Comment: So adding dw.groupby(['Unspsc Desc', 'Total_Price','Year_Purchase']) ??

Comment: You only have to pass in the name of the column you want to group by